# ParseError when trying to send XML string to Carrot2 server

Tags: python, xml, http, post, carrot2

When I send this request to my Carrot2 server:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
my_url = 'http://localhost:8080/dcs/rest?dcs.c2stream=xml'
xml_string = etree.tostring(xml)
http.request(my_url, 'POST', body=xml_string, headers={'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    'status': '400', 
    'content-length': '1571', 
    'server': 'Jetty(7.3.1.v20110307)', 
    'cache-control': 'must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store', 
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 
    'content-type': 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'
}, 
<html>\n
<head>\n
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>\n
    <title>Error 400 Could not parse Carrot2 XML stream: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]\nMessage: Content is not allowed in prolog.</title>\n
</head>\n
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>\n
    <p>Problem accessing /dcs/rest. Reason:\n
        <pre>    Could not parse Carrot2 XML stream: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]\nMessage: Content is not allowed in prolog.</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>\n
</body>\n
</html>\n
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm not sure what to look for to find the problem

Edit:
I built the XML string using the following code

```
xml = etree.Element('searchresult')
etree.SubElement(xml, 'query').text = 'dogs are fantastic pets'
for result in search_results:
    doc = etree.Element('document')
    etree.SubElement(doc, 'title').text = result['title'].replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', '').replace('</b', '')
    etree.SubElement(doc, 'snippet').text = result['abstract'].replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', '').replace('</b', '')
    etree.SubElement(doc, 'url').text = result['url'].replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', '').replace('</b', '')
    xml.append(doc)
```

Comment: What is the XML string you are posting?

Comment: @stanislaw.osinski I have added the code I used to build the XML string to the question

Comment: One problem is that you're sending an incorrect content-type...

Comment: Which content type should I be using?

Comment: @JosiahWitt The error message you're seeing is often a result of the XML string starting with something else than a white space or the opening brace. Can you post the actual XML string that you are submitting?

Comment: @JosiahWitt You can also try the [3.9.3 prerelease DCS](http://download.carrot2.org/head/3.9.3-SNAPSHOT/carrot2-dcs-3.9.3-SNAPSHOT.zip) which will dump the input XML to the console in case of parse errors.

Comment: @stanislaw.osinski This is the beginning of the string I am trying to send

>>> xml_string[:70]

'<searchresult><query>dogs are fantastic pets</query><document><title>A'

Comment: Thanks for your help @stanislaw.osinski, I believe it is working correctly now. :)